# Retentar uma requisição após 5 segundos em caso de erro

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso retentar minha requisição http após 5 segundos em caso de erro.

Tentei implementar com `retryWhen` mas recebo:

> Property 'retryWhen' does not exist on type 'Observable'. [2339]

Tentei assim:

```
  listaDepartamentos(){
    this.myservice.consultaDepartamentos()
    .pipe(
      take(1)
    )
    .retryWhen(error => {
      return error
         .flatMap((error: any) => {
            if(error.status  === 503) {
              return Observable.of(error.status).delay(5000)
            }
            return Observable.throw({error: 'No retry'});
         })
         .take(5)
         .concat(Observable.throw({error: 'Sorry, there was an error (after 5 retries)'}));
      });
    .subscribe((res) => {
     console.log(res)
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err)

    })
  }
```

No meu serviço:

```
consultaDepartamentos():Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'global/departamento/listar',
    {observe: 'response'})
}
```

Comment: Você está importando  o operador?

Comment: sim, ele encontra o operador

Comment: da uma olhada neste exemplo, talvez possa ajudar https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwnknr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Vou tentar. você poderia adicionar uma resposta explicando o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do rxjs 5.5, a forma recomendada de encadear operadores é utilizando o `pipe`. A [documentação explica](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) o porque.

Em vez de fazer:

```
$observable.map(...)
    .filter(...)
    .mergeMap(...)
    .subscribe(...)
```

Você deve fazer assim:

```
import { map, filter, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

$observable.pipe(
    map(...),
    filter(...),
    mergeMap(...),
)
.subscribe(...)
```

O seu código ficaria assim:

```
this.myservice.consultaDepartamentos()
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    retryWhen(error => error.pipe(
        flatMap((error: any) => {
            if(error.status === 503) {
              return of(error.status).pipe(delay(5000))
            }
            return throwError({error: 'No retry'});
        }),
        take(5),
        concat(throwError({error: 'Sorry, there was an error (after 5 retries)'})),
    ))
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    }
  )
```